# c# array Linear Search

Tags: c#, arrays

So in this array each number is a result and the index of that result is a number assigned to the person that gave the result. 
I need to find out which scorer has given the highest results for all rows in the array. So say results[0-3,3] was scorer 3 for all rows how do I find out which scorer has given out the highest results for all rows in total?
an example of the output would be

so the example of the output would be "Scorer 4 gave the highest average score of 9"

```
int[,] results ={//Each number is a scorer's score
                          { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6},//competitor 1
                          { 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5},//competitor 2
                            { 2, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10}
                         };
```

Comment: *...for all rows in total?* - What will be result for your example?

Comment: how would you identify which competitor scored highest by Index?? .. And What have you tried so far?

Comment: so the example of the output would be "Scorer 4 gave the highest average score of 9"

Comment: Given your data above, and assuming that the first number is Scorer 1's score, then I think Scorer 5 has the highest average of 8.6666. Can you explain why you say Scorer 4 has the highest average of 9?

Comment: Hello, it was an example. It wasn't actually stating the actual highest average  Enigmativity

Comment: @DanielWilliams - Which makes it a bit confusing. Can you please confirm what the correct output would be for the sample data you provided?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like from your question that you want to know which **column** (the scorer) has the highest average score, not which **row** (which would be the competitor and not the scorer).

Here's how I would do it:

```
var bestScorer =
    results
        .OfType<int>()
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .GroupBy(xn => xn.n % results.GetLength(1))
        .Select(gxns => new
        {
            average = gxns.Average(xn => xn.x),
            scorer = gxns.Key + 1,
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.average)
        .Select(x =>
            String.Format(
                "Scorer {0} gave the highest average score of {1}",
                x.scorer,
                x.average))
        .First();
```

This gives the result of:

```
Scorer 5 gave the highest average score of 8.66666666666667
```

If you change the string format to `"Scorer {0} gave the highest average score of {1:0}"` then you get:

```
Scorer 5 gave the highest average score of 9
```

If you do want rows/competitors then change the `%` to `/` and this would work still.

---

Doing this with a loop would look like this:

```
var best = new { scorer = -1, average = double.MinValue };
for (var j = 0; j < results.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        total += results[i, j];
    }
    var current = new { scorer = j + 1, average = (double)total / results.GetLength(0) };
    if (current.average > best.average)
    {
        best = current;
    }
};
var output =
    String.Format(
        "Scorer {0} gave the highest average score of {1}",
        best.scorer,
        best.average);
```

I get the same output as above.

Comment: are you able to do it with a loop? without using ofType, .Select, .Groupby, .first()?

Comment: @DanielWilliams - Yes, but why?

Comment: @DanielWilliams - I've added a looping solution.

Answer (score -1):

Using a List<> with linq

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> results = new  List<List<int>>() {//Each number is a scorer's score
                          new List<int>(){ 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6},//competitor 1
                          new List<int>(){ 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5},//competitor 2
                          new List<int>(){ 2, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10}
                         };

            var max = results.Select((x, i) => new
            {
                total = x.Sum(),
                index = i
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.total).Take(1);
        }
```

Comment: is there any way without using a list ?

Comment: You could use a KeyValuePair to return two items, but you seem to be rejecting a lot of good solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that it may occur that some competitors can get equal score. `bestScorersIds` is a list of indexes of a competitors having maximum total score.

```
int[,] results ={//Each number is a scorer's score
                      { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6},//competitor 1
                      { 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5},//competitor 2
                        { 2, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10}
                     };

var max = Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(0))
    .Max(i => Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(1)).Sum(j => results[i,j]));
var bestScorersIds = Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(0))
    .Where(i => Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(1)).Sum(j => results[i, j]) == max)
    .ToList();
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/Glk0jG)

Alternative solution with loops:

```
int[,] results ={//Each number is a scorer's score
                      { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6},//competitor 1
                      { 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5},//competitor 2
                        { 2, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10}
                     };

List<int> bestScorersIds = new List<int>();
int bestScore = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < results.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int tempScore = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < results.GetLength(1); j++)
        tempScore += results[i, j];
    if (tempScore < bestScore) continue;
    if(tempScore > bestScore) bestScorersIds.Clear();
    bestScorersIds.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: and without using Enumerable.Range?

Comment: @Daniel Williams, it is possible to achieve the same behaviour with loops.